# Can a Chef Server have multiple workstations?

Tags: continuous-integration, chef-infra, continuous-deployment, chef-recipe, continuous-delivery

We have a predefined configuration of the infrastructure where the nodes have a particular runlist of recipes controlled using a central Chef server and workstation.

I want to implement a knife command to force a deploy recipe to be run on all the nodes. Is it possible just to run the knife -o recipe command from a new workstation and let the server sync all the recipes from the central workstation itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use multiple workstations, but not quite the way you describe. When you push a cookbook (or policy) it gets uploaded into the Chef Server. All client nodes only talk to your Chef Server, not the workstation. That includes cookbooks and run lists (unless overridden with `-o` as you noted). So you can run `knife ssh somequery sudo chef-client` from any workstation any have it function the same.

Comment: My bad, I meant to include the "knife -o recipe" command in a knife ssh command. My question, which may be a bit trivial is that configuring a second workstation with the chef server configurations will not lead to retrieval or syncing of the recipes from the workstation to the chef server, if I just intend to use the knife ssh command, right?

Comment: In the sense that, syncing the cookbooks is only automated between the chef server and the chef nodes, but uploading the cookbooks onto the chef server is manual using the knife upload command.

Comment: Correct, you have to chose when to upload cookbooks.